# Responsive dropdown menu is reloading my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

If anyone is reading this, please help. I have a responsive menu I created with a tutorial, it uses css and just a code in javascript (which I don't know nothing, I just copy/paste), and it works fine. The problem starts when I insert this menu inside a div in my site. The desktop version works still fine, but the mobile version is a different story. The button calls the dropdown menu, but when I press the projects button it reloads the page and never shows me the projects.

For better understanding, I uploaded two sites, please check them on your phone if possible:

- one with the menu free on a blank page 
  http://armandorodriguez.pe/menu

  jsfiddle.net/xj82ugwz/
- and one with the menu inside a div 
  http://armandorodriguez.pe/info

  jsfiddle.net/2p66rvz9/

Now you can see the menu in the second link is inside a div called 'header-menu' which is inside another div called 'header', and that is how it's supposed to be in my page. What is wrong and how can I solve this??

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the pertinent code that affects your menu. It's a problem with the menu being inside the responsive menu. I'm guessing you're mixing two different plugins that are't compatible.

Comment: the problem seems to be in the css,jquery seems fine.the solution below is the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your portfolio has an empty `href` attribute, change this to `#`.

Under the `li` item with the class `submenu` change

`<a href="">` to `<a href="#">`.

---

A bit of javascript can solve your next problem. You detect if the user is using a mobile device, if so, you set the `href` attribute to `#`. Otherwise you remove the `href` attribute. Give the portfolio link an `id` to make things easier.

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    document.getElementById("YOUR ID").href = "#";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("YOUR ID").removeAttribute("href");
}
```

This should solve all of your problems.

Comment: and btw, now I'm seeing another problem, not as important as the other one but still. now if I press the portfolio button (in desktop mode) it will close the submenu and it won't appear or disappear unless I click on portfolio again, which is why I erased the '#' now that I remember.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. I mean it removes the hand if I hover on that button, but If I press it it still won't show/close the submenu unless I click again, just like before.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late response. Opening a new question will allow me and others to assist you in the best possible way. Please include another example in the new question.

Comment: no problem man. I did, here's the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713109/responsive-menu-on-hover-submenu-shows-error .Hope someone has the answer.