# Responsive menu: on hover submenu shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Big story short: I created a responsive menu from a tutorial. The menu is supposed to show the submenu when you hover on portfolio button, and when on mobile mode you need to press the button to show the submenu (that works fine). The problem is that the tutorial had a error: if you press the portfolio button in desktop mode the submenu will not show again unless you press (click) the button, like in mobile mode.

Here's the live example: http://armandorodriguez.pe/info

I tried to write the code here but didn't understand the instructions, so here's the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/x44w1twf/

So basically what i need is that if I'm on desktop mode it always shows the submenu on hover, even if I press the portfolio button, and in mobile only when i press the button. Now I suppose this can be solved with a simple code in js, but I don't know nothing of js, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle to see it  working http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/x44w1twf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thin is that when you click on the element to hide it that set the style inline `display: none` and that overwrite the style:

```
header nav ul li:hover .children {
    display:block;
}
```

So add !important to the style like this:

```
header nav ul li:hover .children {
    display:block !important;
}
```

[Here a working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/x44w1twf/1/)

For the normal behavior in mobile just add the style inside a media like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {    
    header nav ul li:hover .children {
       display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey yandy, it works for the desktop mode, but now the mobile mode doesn't work correctly. try it on your phone if you can so you can see what i mean. thanks

Comment: @AdamXpelled I update the answer to fix the error in mobile.

Comment: thanks man, but it doesn't work, mobile is still wrong. i also tried setting display:none !important; inside the media, but then the menu kinda crashes, like if it's getting the two !important commands at the same time. any ideas?

Comment: Is a @media (min-width: 800px)

Comment: Bro you have to remove the `header nav ul li:hover .children {
       display:block !important;
    }` and add the `media` that i post, I'm doing it in your site and it works.

Comment: wait, if i remove the header nav ul li:hover .children { display:block !important; } it won't show the submenu on hover in desktop mode. and if i add header nav ul li:hover .children {display:block !important;} to the @media, it will work on hover on mobile mode, and that's not what i want, but the opposite (to press the button on mobile). is that what you mean?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. When you remove the `header nav ul li:hover .children { display:block !important; }` and add it to the `@media (min-width: 800px)`  it only show on hover when the min-width is above of 800px  (desktop mode) and that is what you want, Correct me if not.

Comment: It worked! You did it! I read it wrong, but now it works correctly on both view modes. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.